# Path to learn Qiskit as a tool for the future

Tags: programming, qiskit, resource-request

I am an undergraduate in Engineering physics, yet to take classes on Quantum mechanics, but none (if I'm not mistaken) on quantum information and quantum algorithms, and I am curious about the subject so I've began reading some things to get the basics on quantum computing (I've been reading *Quantum Computing since Democritus* by Scott Anderson) so as to move afterwards to Qiskit.

As for Qiskit learning, I am a bit lost, as it is such a new concept, there are little to none tutorials available online, I only found a collection of *Jupyter Notebooks* on GitHub (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials) that, however helpful, are overwelming and seem directed to someone that already needs to learn Qiskit and has a project that needs it. My goal to learn it is to be ready for when I need it, to just add a tool in my toolbox. But to do so I need some advice for I am stuck.

Also, I would like to ask if anyone knows any online course with verified certificate's related to the subject.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Hi, Bidon. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! My two cents: you'll probably get bored very soon if you start learning Qiskit as a "tool for the future". Instead, pick up an actual project which *requires* Qiskit, and learn the language on the go. For a start, go through [Quantum Algorithm Implementations for Beginners](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719). Choose any one algorithm in that paper, and try to implement it yourself in Qiskit by consulting the official documentation. If you're stuck, look at the solution or ask here.

Comment: Thank you @Blue, that is actually very helpful, if I may ask, what is your opinion on how much quantum theory does one have to know to be able to get up to speed with this new tech? It is a weird question, I admit, but as I'm only to have QM next year, I'm a bit worried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a certificate, check out these [MIT courses](https://quantumcurriculum.mit.edu/) that you can participate in online. They are done in collaboration with IBM.

IBM also recently gave awards for university level courses that use Qiskit. You can find all the best submissions [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/tree/awards/community/awards/teach_me_quantum_2018). These are also courses you can follow along at home (though there won't be a certificate).

Regarding the Jupyter notebook tutorials, I'd suggest starting with [this one](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/awards/community/games/Hello_Qiskit.ipynb) which is an interactive guide to basic quantum operations.

For advice for when you are stuck, I'd suggest the quantum computing stack exchange. I'm sure I don't need to provide a link for that ;)

*Disclosure: I work for IBM.*

Answer (score 0):

Since 2021 IBM has started offering a certification exam called ["IBM Certified Associate Developer - Quantum Computation using Qiskit v0.2X"](https://www.ibm.com/training/certification/C0010300), probably the first professional certification exam for Quantum Computation.